# SEL performSelector and arguments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

It seems like there should be an easy way to call a selector with some arguments when all you have is a SEL object. I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

```
-(MyClass*) init: (SEL)sel owner:(NSObject*) parent
{
   int i =10;
   [parent performSelector:sel:i  ];
}
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Take a look at the [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. In this case:

```
[parent performSelector:sel withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

(note this method is actually listed in the [`NSObject` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCFACCF) documentation). Since `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]` requires an object argument, you will have to write a wrapper in parent's class like

```
-(void)myMethodForNumber:(NSNumber*)number {
    [self myMethod:[number intValue]];
}
```

to unbox the `NSNumber`.

If you really want to invoke a method that takes non-object arguments directly (for example, you don't have control of the callee source and don't want to add a category), you can use [`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocation):

```
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[parent methodSignatureForSelector:sel]];
[inv setSelector:sel];
[inv setTarget:parent];
[inv setArgument:&i atIndex:2]; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set by NSInvocation
[inv invoke];
```

On a side note, your method looks like an `init` method, but does not follow the correct initializer pattern for Objective-C. You need to call the super-classes initializer, and you need to test for a `nil` result from that call and you must return self from the initializer method. In all cases, your Objective-C initializer methods should look like:

```
-(id)myInitMethod {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
      //perform initialization of self
    }

    return self;
}
```

Your method (if it's an init method) would then look like:

```
-(id) init: (SEL)sel owner:(NSObject*) parent
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self != nil) {
       int i = 10;
       NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[parent methodSignatureForSelector:sel]];
       [inv setSelector:sel];
       [inv setTarget:parent];
       [inv setArgument:&i atIndex:2]; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set by NSInvocation
       [inv invoke];
   }

    return self;
}
```

To be more Objective-C stylistically, I would rename the initializer `-(id)initWithSelector:owner:` as well.

Comment: thanks, this goes above and beyond. I had guessed that I may need to use NSInvocation but was not sure. Great answer.

Comment: As an aside, even if you don't have control over the callee, you could still write a wrapper method using a category on that class to unbox the object into the primitive type.

Comment: A mistake - `[inv setSelector:inv];` should be `[inv setSelector:sel];`?

Answer (score 12):

what Barry Wark said is great.. i have just modified the discussion for lazy programmers

```
-(void)myMethodWith:(int)number andBOOL:(BOOL) someBool andStr:(NSString *)str{
    NSLog(@"%d %d %@",number,someBool,str);
}

-(void) testMethod{
    SEL sel = @selector(myMethodWith:andBOOL:andStr:);
    int i = 10;
    BOOL bol = YES;
    NSString *str = @"hey baby !";
    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:sel]];
    [inv setSelector:sel];
    [inv setTarget:self];
    [inv setArgument:&i atIndex:2]; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set by NSInvocation
    [inv setArgument:&bol atIndex:3];
    [inv setArgument:&str atIndex:4];
    [inv invoke];
}
```

Comment: yunas, I tried your code for NSInvocation. Six years on you’re probably in a different head space but if you can spare a moment perhaps you can see what I’ve missed. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/q/51734605/2348597

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `performSelector:withObject:` The tricky part is converting the `int` to an NSObject. You cannot use `performSelector` with messages that take `int` params, it must instead take an `id`.

From the [NSObject Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:):

> aSelector should identify a method that takes a single argument of type id. For methods with other argument types and return values, use [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocation).

Once that change is made, you can do:

```
id arg = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];    
[parent performSelector:sel withObject:arg];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject  withObject:(id)anotherObject
```

Or if you need to use more complex method use `NSInvocation` class

Answer (score 1):

For methods that take one or two objects of type `id` as arguments, you can use:

```
[parent performSelector:sel withObject:argument1];
```

or

```
[parent performSelector:sel withObject:argument1 withObject:argument2];
```

For methods with other argument types, create an `NSInvocation` that can encapsulate arbitrary method calls.

Comment: Be sure to quantify the exact method signature e.g. NSSelectorFromFromString(methodWithArg1:arg2:)