# Using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with non-object parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I want to invoke `setEditing:animated:` on a table view with a slight delay. Normally, I'd use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` but

1. pSwOaD only accepts one parameter
2. the second parameter to `setEditing:animated:` is a primitive BOOL - not an object

In the past I would create a dummy method in my own class, like `setTableAnimated` and then call `[self performSelector:@selector(setTableAnimated) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f` but that feels kludgy to me.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not use a dispatch_queue ?

```
  double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
  dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
  dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      [tableView setEditing …];
  });
```

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted, seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: if you are using iOS4 this is the way to do it

Answer (score 17):

You need to use [`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

See this code, taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716143/sel-performselector-and-arguments/2716195#2716195), and I've changed it slightly to match your question:

```
BOOL yes = YES;
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self.tableView methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setEditing:Animated:)]];
[inv setSelector:@selector(setEditing:Animated:)];
[inv setTarget:self.tableView];
[inv setArgument:&yes atIndex:2]; //this is the editing BOOL (0 and 1 are explained in the link above)
[inv setArgument:&yes atIndex:3]; //this is the animated BOOL
[inv performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
```

Comment: I think using a var name like `BOOL _yes = YES` is a little clearer, since it alleviates a little confusion as to whether you've got a typo (yes vs YES).

Comment: Also just wanted to point out, the reason for using a variable for `YES` instead of just passing the bool directly: `NSInvocation` throws an exception: `[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]: NULL address argument`, [explained in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11061349/146517).

Answer (score 1):

The selector `setEditing:animated:` is not compatible with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`. You can only call methods with 0 or 1 arguments and the argument (if any) MUST be an object. So your workaround is the way to go. You can wrap the BOOL value in an `NSValue` object and pass it to your `setTableAnimated` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your head around it, use an NSInvocation grabber to make an invocation object & call it with a delay with 1 line instead of many: http://overooped.com/post/913725384/nsinvocation

Comment: Hardly one line if it involves creating a class.