# Passing BOOL to makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I want to pass BOOL to `[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:]` as a parameter.  E.g.

```
[buttons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject: NO];
```

The above code won't work because withObject only accepts id.

What's the right way to do it?

I seen some code with this:

```
[buttons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject: (id)kCFBooleanTrue];
[buttons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject: (id)kCFBooleanFalse];
```

This works fine on 4.2 simulator but fails on 4.2 iphone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write a UIButton (or even UIView) category that allows you to use setEnabled: with an object.

```
@interface UIButton(setEnabledWithObject)
- (void)setEnabledWithNSNumber:(NSNumber *)bNum;
@end

@implementation UIButton(setEnabledWithObject)
- (void)setEnabledWithNSNumber:(NSNumber *)bNum {
    [self setEnabled:[bNum boolValue]];
}
@end
```

and then you could use

```
[buttons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabledWithNSNumber:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[buttons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabledWithNSNumber:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Comment: Thanks!  This will work.  I wish they have simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

I recall one had to do something else than just `withObject:@YES` but since I can't find it anymore I figured out it works as well with

```
[buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSButton *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
    {[item setEnabled:YES];}];
```

Or the faster/older/readabler :) way:

```
for (NSButton *item in buttons) {[item setEnabled:YES];};
```

One should know that enumerateObjectsUsingBlock isn't particularily fast, but it shouldn't be a huge killer here anyways :) If you want fast you can also do that with a `for (;;)` block, sure :)

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the following duplicate questions:

[How to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with primitive types in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904515/how-to-use-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-primitive-types-in-cocoa).

[Using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with non-object parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210733/using-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-non-object-parameters)

[SEL performSelector and arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716143/sel-performselector-and-arguments)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **Passing the BOOL parameters in static** then my answer in [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075620/iphone-performselector-with-bool-parameter/20513727#20513727) will be helpful..