# Perform selector with bool property

Tags: objective-c

I want to implement something like this

```
 [self perform Selector:@selector(setEarlierMessagesIsLoading:) withObject:@YES afterDelay:1];
```

But it not working. Why? Is it possible ?

Resolved with

```
 [self perform Selector:@selector(setEarlierMessagesIsLoading:) withObject:YES afterDelay:1];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: performSelector with BOOL parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075620/iphone-performselector-with-bool-parameter)

Comment: You are sending an `NSNumber` instance to `setEarlierMessagesIsLoading:` method

Comment: Define "not working". Show your `setEarlierMessagesIsLoading:` method. Explain what is happening compared to what you expect to happen.

Comment: BTW - using `dispatch_after` is much clearer and easier than using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

Comment: Your "resolution" is not valid. Do not do what you propose.

Comment: Your "resolution" is not valid. Try my answer, do not do things by guessing.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `@YES` is not a BOOL value, it is an instance of NSNumber.

So if you wanna get a bool value, you have to convert it to a BOOL value.

in you selector

```
- (void)setEarlierMessagesIsLoading:(NSNumber *)isLoading {
    if([isLoading boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"Is it loading? YES");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Is it loading? NO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not code your `if/else` like that. Instead, simply do: `if ([isLoading boolValue]) { // YES } else { // NO }`. Never directly compare a `BOOL` value against `YES` or `NO`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for pointing out my insufficient. You're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your method looks like this:

```
- (void)setEarlierMessagesIsLoading:(BOOL)isLoading;
```

Change to:

```
- (void)setEarlierMessagesIsLoading:(NSNumber *)isLoading;
```

Since you are sending in a NSNumber * and not a BOOL.