# How to pass on string parameter to another method through button selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, performselector

I have this below delegate method that receives **stickerURLString** as input:

```
- (void)selectedSticker:(NSString *)stickerURLString {
    //...
        [self.stickerPreviewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendStickerPreviewButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //...
}
```

And the selector calls this method **sendStickerPreviewButtonPressed**:

```
- (void)sendStickerPreviewButtonPressed: (NSString *)stickerURLString {
    [self.delegate InputFunctionView:self sendSticker:stickerURLString];
}
```

As you can see in order to make this work as expected I have to pass on **stickerURLString** from **selectedSticker** method to **sendStickerPreviewButtonPressed**.

I have tried this:

```
[self.stickerPreviewButton performSelector:@selector(sendStickerPreviewButtonPressed:) withObject:stickerURLString];
```

instead of this:

```
[self.stickerPreviewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendStickerPreviewButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But I got "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" error.

So anyone knows how to pass on string parameter to another method through button selector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach parameter to button.addTarget action in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814646/attach-parameter-to-button-addtarget-action-in-swift)

Comment: declare a global variable and assign the value inside your method.

Comment: @AnuradhS yes it seems the way for me to go about using global variable even though I try to avoid that as my code is quite complex. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using performSelector to call the function then you can use this variation

- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector 
         withObject:(id)object;

**Documentation**

https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418764-performselector

---

You can also check on this answer where another solution is explained, in my opinion probably more complex but useful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161831/1502070

Answer (score 0):

For UIControl object function 1st parameter is id type, passes by control itself , you get uibutton object as a parameter in sendStickerPreviewButtonPressed: function which is not convertible to string , So you got an error, You may pass string By extending UIbutton class by your custom class . then Create button of your own class, anr get you custom property form sender button .

```
     -(void)sendStickerPreviewButtonPressed:(mycustomButton*)sender{
      //sender.myCustomString
}
```