# Objective-C ARC: how to convert (void *)YES passed as an argument?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, selector

I have an array of views, and I need to hide them all, so I use:

```
BOOL shouldHideViews = YES;
[allViews makeObjectPerformSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:(void *)shouldHideViews]
```

When I convert the code to ARC, it tells me I need some bridged cast, then I changed:

```
(void *)shouldHideViews
```

to

```
(__bridge BOOL)shouldHideViews
```

it says incompatible types casting 'int' to 'BOOL' with a __bridge cast

So how do I do it? I know I can just iterate all the views in the array, but this is not the point, I want to know in general what I should do to make this ARC compatible.

Thanks!

Comment: Done use arc for automatic-reference-counting questions. Explanation here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137914/disambiguate-the-arc-tag/137934#comment387066_137914

Comment: Was this a working piece of code before ARC?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, yeah, it magically works. I just ran into another guy doing this last week. It gets turned into a pointer to 0x1 I believe, and it kind of just works it way through the system as a "true enough."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers indicating that you can't pass `YES` this way are correct. There are easier solutions however:

```
[allViews setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: shouldHideViews] forKey:@"hidden"];
```

This works because NSArray overrides its `setValue:forKey:` for exactly this use.

You can also now use blocks:

```
[allViews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
  ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){ [obj setHidden:shouldHideViews];}];
```

Or the tried and true `for()` loop (see @rob mayoff's answer.)

Of them, I generally just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can't pass primitive types as a void pointer. You should keep the boolean variable as an instance variable and reference it in the setHidden. That way you can just do this:

```
shouldHideViews = YES; //declare BOOL shouldHideViews; in your .h file
[allViews makeObjectPerformSelector:@selector(setHidden) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: I know what you are saying, but setHidden: is a method in UIView, and I have an array of views, so it is not something I can control unless I subclass the view.

Comment: Subclass NSArray! You can create a method in your subclassed NSArray that sends setHidden: to all of the UIViews in your array. Make sure that when you loop through all of the objects in the array, you're checking that it's a UIView before sending it setHidden:, or else your app will crash.

Answer (score 1):

These will be rather helpful to you

[How to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with primitive types in Cocoa?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904515/how-to-use-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-primitive-types-in-cocoa)

[Using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with non-object parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210733/using-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-with-non-object-parameters)

[SEL performSelector and arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716143/sel-performselector-and-arguments)

Either you should make a wrapper using `NSNumber` or use `NSInvocation`.

Answer (score 1):

The `object` argument to `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` is of type `id`.  That means it needs to point to an Objective-C object.  Casting a non-object to an `id` is a bad idea, because the system (particularly under ARC) is allowed to do things like send the `retain` and `release` messages to an `id`, and that will crash if you cast `YES` to `id`.

I suggest just using fast enumeration:

```
for (UIView *view in allViews) {
    view.hidden = shouldHideViews;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I personally like the fast enumeration too, but for whatever reason the OP does not like that answer.