# How can I pass multiple objects to a delayed method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

How can I pass

`-(void)explosionFromPoint:(CGPoint)explosionPoint withSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite;`

in a

`[self performSelector:@selector(//Right here) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];`?

You cant put the whole selector inside the `@selector()`,  and `withObject`first of all only allows one object to be passed over, and neither do I understand how to use it.

How can I pass a method with objects after a delay?
I also tried a workaround where I call

`[self performSelector:@selector(waitExplosion) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];`
which then runs the action itself, `[self explosionFromPoint:c0TileCoord withSprite:bomb];`
, but this is a really bad way to do it as I have to re-declare the variables and it's just bad.

How can I pass a method with objects after a delay?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716143/sel-performselector-and-arguments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use dispatch_after.

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self explosionFromPoint:aPoint withSprite:sprite]; 
});
```

Where aPoint and sprite are defined outside of your block.

Comment: this is not the exact replacement for `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` because GCD `dispatch_after` cannot be cancelled whereas `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` can be cancelled with `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. What about `[self schedule:@selector(aMethod:CCSprite)];` with arguments?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pass multiple arguments to a method using ***performSelector:*** , keep all the arguments in a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` and then pass that array/dictionary like

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(testWith:) withObject:array afterDelay:3];
```

**Edit**

```
  NSArray *array =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"arg1",@"arg2"];
 [self performSelector:@selector(testWith:) withObject:array afterDelay:3];


 -(void)testWith:(NSArray *)array
 {

   NSString * arg1 =[array objectAtIndex:0];// first argument
   NSString *arg2 = [array objectAtIndex:1];// second argument
   // do other stuff
 }
```

Comment: And how do I set up the array?

Comment: Create an array with your arguments..Pass array.. In the received method you know the order of arguments in the array. Take the arguments in the corrected order..

Comment: To be more clear use a dictionary with keys to identify each arguments.. pass it.. retrieve the objects back

Comment: What do I call the recieving method? `-(void)test:(NSString *)testwith{}`?

Comment: The dispatch-answer worked for me this time, so I accepted that instead. Will use this for other stuff though, thanks for teaching me something!

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach you can use is to pass an `NSArray` or an `NSMutableArray` as parameter to your method.
An Example:

```
NSString *firstItem = @"first Item";
NSNumber *secondItem = [[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
YourCustomObject *thirdItem= [[YourCustomObject alloc] init];

//your array to pass
NSArray *arrayToPass = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem, nil];

//call you method after delay and pass all the objects:
[self oerformSelector:@selector(doStuffWithMultipleParams:) withObject:arrayToPass afterDelay:3.0f];
```

The method could be used like this:

```
 - (void)doStuffWithMultipleParams:(NSArray *)passedArray{
    String *s; 
    BOOL b;
    YourCustomObject *obj;
    if ([[passedArray objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        s = [passedArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([[passedArray objectAtIndex:1] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
        b = [[passedArray objectAtIndex:1] boolValue];
    }
    if ([[passedArray objectAtIndex:1] isKindOfClass:[YourCustomObject class]]){
        obj = [passedArray objectAtIndex:2];
    }
    if (s || b || obj){
        //now do stuff with these objects
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject). For your case you can make use of another method of NSObject. ie

`- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object1 withObject:(id)object2;`

But unfortunately in this method you can not give the delay.