# peformSelector with two arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

I've to run this method on background or in new thread. How to pass two arguments in performSelector?

```
[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo updateUI:NO];

-(void)addMessageFromRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo updateUI:(BOOL)updateUI
{
}
```

Comment: This will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716143/sel-performselector-and-arguments/9108934#9108934

Comment: see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731105/how-can-i-pass-multiple-objects-to-a-delayed-method/16731378#16731378

Answer (score 1):

If you must use performSelector and you want N parameters, simply wrap them in an array or dictionary and make the signature of the called method have a single parameter of NSArray or NSDictionary. Any primitive types (like int, float, etc.) will need to be wrapped in NSNumber.

Example With NSArray:

```
- (void) addMessageFromRemoteNotification:(NSArray*)parameters
{
}

...

[self performSelector:@selector(addMessageFromRemoteNotification:)
withObject:@[ obj1, obj2, obj3, @(4.0f)]];
```

Example With NSDictionary:

```
- (void) addMessageFromRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)parameters
{
}

...

[self performSelector:@selector(addMessageFromRemoteNotification:)
withObject:@{ @"prop1": @"prop1value", @"prop2": @(4.0f) }];
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'd go for a NSDictionary instead of a NSArray, but this answers the question :)

Comment: Updated to show an NSDictionary example

Answer (score 0):

there is method

```
[self performSelector:@selector(addMessageFromRemoteNotification:) withObject:param1 withObject:param2];
```

you can use this.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate addMessageFromRemoteNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21c7b0'

Comment: I got this exception...

Comment: I am pretty sure `-performSelector:withObject:withObject:` is just made up.

Comment: @GradyPlayer No, it is a real method, but it does not send the message to a background thread.  Check the header.

Comment: @dineshsurya Read the error message.  Your `AppDelegate` does not implement that method.  Has nothing to do with the `performSelector:...` call;   not that this particular call would solve your problem anyway.

Comment: @bbum oh yeah I now see it is in ios... sorry

Comment: The selector name is incomplete. If you give it two parameters, you will need two colons in your selector name.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a model class for the data you want to send, eg -

```
@interface Car : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *manufacturer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *colour;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *year;

@end
```

Then pass an instance of it in your performSelector: method.

It's often better than passing multiple parameters anyway, in case you decide to change the data model (eg, add more properties) - though it will depend on the circumstances of course.

Comment: This isn't wrong, but it is a little heavy-handed; just use a dictionary... that is what the framework does everywhere: `NSDictionary * userInfo`

Comment: Also probably a matter of programming style, or if the parameters suit it (eg, if you're often using multiple parameters in your code, would a dedicated model make things clearer)