# performSelector "backgroundRefreshStatus" crashes on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am building with Xcode 5/iOS SDK 6.1. If the app runs on an iOS 7.x device it should check whether the setting "Settings -> General -> BackgroundAppRefresh" is set for the app. Since this property is only available on iOS 7 I am doing:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)])
{
    NSInteger outcome=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)] integerValue];
    //do something with "outcome"
}
```

However... the app crashes on iOS 7 at the "performSelector" line which is strange because it passes the "respondsToSelector" call?? Anyone knows why? I also tried NSSelectorFromString(@"backgroundRefreshStatus") with the same result.

Comment: You need id outcome=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];

Comment: If using ARC, assigning an integer to an `id` is likely going to crash.

Comment: why are you building against 6.1 if you want to use iOS 7 features?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited the original post. It still crashes on iOS 7 devices.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a lot of unnecessary code there. Unless the `backgroundRefreshStatus` selector exists before iOS 7 as a private API you don't need the version check.

Your use of `@selector` is also incorrect and you don't need to use `performSelector`, just call the method:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)]) {
    UIBackgroundRefreshStatus refreshStatus = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus];
}
```

Comment: It won´t compile with iOS 6 SDK because neither "UIBackgroundRefreshStatus" nor "backgroundRefreshStatus" is defined there!

Comment: You should really be developing with the iOS 7 SDK and enabling backwards compatibility with iOS 6 by using techniques like checking if a receiver `respondsToSelector`, rather than using an old SDK and trying to be 'forwards compatible'. If you insist on using an older SDK (which isn't necessary to achieve compatibility with both iOS 6 & 7) you'll have to use [NSInvocation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2716195/80425) in this case as UIBackgroundRefreshStatus is a primitive type, which is extremely messy.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a string as the selector. Try without the string:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
if([app respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)])
{
    UIBackgroundRefreshStatus outcome = [app performSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];
    // or outcome = [app backgroundRefreshStatus]
}
```

Comment: You are right about the string. It was my fault because in my code it was right. I changed my original post. The problem with your solution is that "UIBackgroundRefreshStatus" is not available within the iOS 6.1 SDK so it will not compile. What I tried was:
    
    NSInteger status=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)] integerValue];

     

but with no success.