# missing some iOS Method in official documentations

Tags: ios, documentation

why i can't find for example the method :

```
  - (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object1 withObject:(id)object2;
```

in official iOS documentation page, and able to used it in Xcode ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you couldn't find it.

It's right here at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:withObject:)

Hover with options key on the function, most of the time it does the trick.

Comment: Ah yes , i was looking in NSObject class reference.
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is in [NSObject protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:withObject:) documentation. 
Duplicate with ([SEL performSelector and arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716143/sel-performselector-and-arguments))

Comment: yep, in NSObject protocol  thanks